# Exclude files and folders when bundling a library with vite

Tags: config, bundle, vite, lib

I am trying to publish a library using vite (via vite.config.ts). My codebase has a storybook and an app setup. However, when I publish my library I only want to include the files under the `lib` folder. I do not want to include the `stories/*`, `App.tsx` and whatever else other folders I have for my app. The following code is my `vite.config.ts` - No matter what, all files under `src/` get included in the dist bundle

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    react({
      jsxImportSource: "@emotion/react",
    }),
  ],
  optimizeDeps: {
    exclude: [
      "react",
      "src/stories",
      "App.d.ts",
      "main.d.ts",
      "stories/*",
    ],
  },
  build: {
    manifest: true,
    minify: true,
    reportCompressedSize: true,
    lib: {
      // Could also be a dictionary or array of multiple entry points
      entry: resolve(__dirname, "src/lib/index.ts"),
      name: "my-awesome-lib",
      // the proper extensions will be added
      fileName: (format) => `my-awesome-lib.${format}.js`,
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      input: ["src/lib/index.ts"],
      // dependencies that should not be include in your lib
      // also have tried it here but it does not work
      external: [
      "react",
      "src/stories",
      "App.d.ts",
      "main.d.ts",
      "stories/*",
    ],
      output: {
        globals: {
          react: "React",
        },
      },
      plugins: [
        typescriptPaths({
          preserveExtensions: true,
        }),
        typescript({
          sourceMap: true,
          declaration: true,
          outDir: "dist",
        }),
      ],
    },
  },
});
```